# Custom UIView property not populating consistently

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm coding in iOS/Objective C and I have and instance where I populate a table view, and when a row is tapped a detail view controller is loaded.  In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method I set the parameters which will be passed to the detail view controller and in turn the view of that view controller.

Code:

```
 newsArticleText = [[newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"article"];
```

In the prepareForSegue method:

```
NewsDetailController *newsDetailController = [segue destinationViewController];

newsDetailController.articleText = newsArticleText;
```

In the detail ViewController's header file:

```
@interface NewsDetailController : UIViewController {

NSString *articleText;

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *articleText;
```

In the detail ViewController's Implementation file we set the parameter's value:

```
(NewsView*)self.view).nArticleText = articleText;
```

and finally in the view whose parent is the detail ViewController:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: nArticleText];


    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((__bridge CFMutableAttributedStringRef) attrString, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), kCTFontAttributeName, font);

    /* Get a framesetter to draw the actual text */
   CTFramesetterRef fs = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge  CFAttributedStringRef) attrString);
   CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(fs, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), pathToRenderIn, NULL);
```

The data source is a JSON array.  After the segue is performed that loads the detail view controller and the custom view, only the first record/object is displayed.  If we return to the table view and select the second or third record, the variable which holds the value has the correct value when printed in the console, but nothing is visible on the screen.

Please advise folks!
-TU